# Storing Base64 Image in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, image, base64, src

Some of the images' base64 string is over 500.000 character. varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) are not able to handle. What's the best way to keep the long strings to be assigned to src attributes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would caution against storing images in sql server. Your Db can grow very huge pretty soon - thereby unnecessarily increasing your backup/restore times;

The best would be to store the images on the file system and simply store the file location in  a DB table. Then you can retrieve the file location from DB and add it to your src attribute. (I am assuming the src attribute is for html images).